# Vertical column at bottom of tabularx table

Tags: tabularx, vertical

I am struggling to remove these two additional vertical lines I have at the bottom of my table. I would be very thankfull towards any help!

```
\begin{table}[H]%
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\centering
\caption{Environmental impact of the production of 1kg CaCO\textsubscript{3} through different metabolic pathways {\citep{Porter}}.}
\begin{tabularx}{15,5cm}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Pathway}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Carbon footprint\\ (CO\textsubscript{2}/FU)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Eutrophication Potential\\ (SO\textsubscript{4}/FU)\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Embodied Energy\\ (MJ)\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
Carbonation & 2,37 & 7,35e-4 & 7,2 \\ \hline
Ureolytic bacteria & 1,51 & 2,4e-1 & 16,1 \\ \hline
Carbonic anhydrase & 0,555 & 2,09e-4 & 0,619 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Completing your code to make it compilable, and replacing `tabularx` with `tabular`, since you have no X column,  I don't obtain these unwanted vertical lines. Could you post a complete compliable code reproducing your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Please, always provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem and which we can compile as it is.
- Extending your code fragment to an MWE, I cant reproduce your problem, but see many other issues in your code:

  - in tabularx should be at least one `X` column of `X` or its derivative column type (see @Bernard comment), since you haven't,  vertical lines are incorrectly aligned
  - why you not use `mhchem` package for chemistry formulae?
  - instead nesting tables in column headers is simpler to use `makecell` package and its instruction; for example

```
\thead{Carbon footprint\\ (\ce{CO2}/FU)}
```

- by using `X` column type you can left breaking cell contents to LaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \centering
    \caption{Environmental impact of the production of 1kg \ce{CaCO3} through different metabolic pathways \citep{Porter}.}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}C|
                                >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}C|
                                >{\hsize=0.9\hsize}C|}
\hline
\textbf{Pathway} & \bfseries Carbon footprint (\ce{CO2}/FU) 
                    & \bfseries Eutrophication Potential (\ce{SO4}/FU) 
                        & \bfseries Embodied Energy (MJ)  \\
    \hline
Carbonation         & 2,37  & 7,35e-4   &  7,2      \\ \hline
Ureolytic bacteria  & 1,51  & 2,4e-1    & 16,1      \\ \hline
Carbonic anhydrase  & 0,555 & 2,09e-4   &  0,619    \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, more simple code and (to my opinion) more nice table you can get with use of `tabularray` and `siunitx` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
   \centering
\caption{Environmental impact of the production of \qty{1}{kg} \ce{CaCO3} through different metabolic pathways \citep{Porter}.}
\label{tab:metabolic?}
\begin{tblr}{colsep=4pt,
             colspec = {@{} l X[0.9, c, si]
                          X[1.2, c, si={table-format=1.2e1}]
                          X[0.9, c, si]
                        @{}},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, guard}
             }
    \toprule
Pathway & Carbon footprint (\ce{CO2}/FU)
                    & Eutrophication Potential (\ce{SO4}/FU)
                        & Embodied Energy (MJ)    \\
    \midrule
Carbonation         & 2,37  & 7,35e-4   &  7,2      \\  
Ureolytic bacteria  & 1,51  & 2,4e-1    & 16,1      \\  
Carbonic anhydrase  & 0,555 & 2,09e-4   &  0,619    \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for you help. I am new to latex and stackexchange so I didn't know all these. I will pay attention in the future!

Comment: @Niki, you are welcome!